# Jqgrid - another way to call onSelectRow

Tags: jqgrid

Normally we call onSelectRow function like:

```
$("#imports_grid").jqGrid({
    // jqGrid settings
    url: url,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: cnames,
    colModel: cmodel,
    onSelectRow: function() {
      // Code
    },
});
```

My PHP script outputs jqGrid settings using json_encode() so it looks like

```
$script = '$("#imports_grid").jqGrid(' . json_encode($js_settings) . ');';
// echo $script;
```

In this case, onSelectRow's function does not work.

Is there an alternative method to fire function inside onSelectRow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mix HTML code and JavaScript code inside of PHP script. Instead of that you can place `<script>` element

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="theURL.js"></script>
```

in the PHP script. The JavaScript code you can place in the .JS file.

**UPDATED**: You can make of cause a mix between inline JavaScript code where you set some *global* variables and the JS file where you use the variables:

in PHP code you use

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MYGLOBALSETTINGS = {
        cnames: ["Column 1", "Column 2", ...],
        cmodel: [{...}, {...}...],
        url: "myUrl"
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
```

and in `my.js` you just use `MYGLOBALSETTINGS.cnames` and `MYGLOBALSETTINGS.cmodel`

```js
$("#imports_grid").jqGrid({
    // jqGrid settings
    url: MYGLOBALSETTINGS.url,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: MYGLOBALSETTINGS.cnames,
    colModel: MYGLOBALSETTINGS.cmodel,
    onSelectRow: function() {
      // Code
    },
});
```

Comment: Actually I wrote "echo" just for illustrative purpose. The $script variable passed to another function and I can not change it :). colNames and colModel are set dynamically too. Also, I want to manage different JqGrid options from UI so the most preferable for me is to collect all those settings and pass it to the json_encode()

Comment: @volocuga: I included more details in the "**UPDATED**" part of my answer. During constructing of the value of `MYGLOBALSETTINGS` you can use any `echo` etc.